# Netbeans project property disable

Tags: netbeans-8, centos7

I am unable to do set my project property. when i do right click of my netbeans project then i can see project property in last option but unable to click property. i am using netbeans 8.0 and centos 7 os. In my laptop its working fine but desktop its not working. i did reset netbeans and reinstall again, I did same configrutaion but proble is same...

```
right-click my projects -> properties //this thing disable
```

anyone know why netbeans project property is disable my desktop only?
I hope here i will get answer.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: when u do right click on project property then where you can see property option mean i think your property option show above taskbar, It is right?

Comment: yes this option show over taskbar...left bottom side.....Charlie can you know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Trat, When you do right click on your netbeans project then property option show in last. so property option is showing over the task bar thats why you are unable to click on property. and you are thinking it is disable.

You need to set your screen resolution if you will use high resolution according your desktop screen then property option will not come over the task bar and you can click that option. I hope this solution will work for you :)

Comment: I changed the resolution of my screen and able to click on property...Thanks Charlie